# Publish a Public Photo on Facebook with iOS Always Private

Tags: ios, facebook, publish, photo

I am using `SLRequest` to post a photo to Facebook.

This is the code I a using:

```
SLRequest *postToMyWall = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook 
                                     requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                     URL:postURL
                                     parameters:postDict];

[postToMyWall addMultipartData:myImageData 
                      withName:@"source"
                          type:@"multipart/form-data"
                      filename:@"myPhoto"];
```

But all uploaded photos are private by default and hence not published on the user's wall.

I asked the user for `publish_stream` and `publish_actions` permissions.

How can I cause the iOS publish the photo on the user's wall instead of just uploading it?

Comment: Which url are you using and what parameters?

Comment: Check default visibility of your app on facebook.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291837/the-permission-of-facebook-post-is-only-me-using-fbwebdialogs

Comment: @Moxy Hi. this is the url: https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos, and the only params are "message" and source.

Comment: @Elto Thank you, but I am using SLRequest (see the code above) with the integrated iOS SDK, and not openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions. I also checked that the app configured and "public" at facebook's website.